# Group matching with grep includes extra characters

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I wanted to extract some text with regex in bash, so I decided to try the following simple example out.

```
echo "abc def ghi" | grep -Po " \K(.*?) "
```

I was expecting to get a `"def"`, but to my surprise a `"def "` (with a final extra space) was what I got.

I'm interested in understanding why `grep` also includes the extra space at the end and how to get rid of it. I know I could post-process the result with another line but I'm interested in solving this with grep.

Comment: Would `" \K(.+)(?= )"` suffice?

Comment: From my preliminary testing, yes!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short:

```
\K
```

causes grep to keep everything ***prior*** to the \K and not include it in the match. It does not affect what comes ***after*** the `\K()`.

This might be enough:

```
" \K(.+)(?= )"
```

Where `(?= )` is a non capturing group.

or perhaps better:

```
" \K([^ ]+)(?= )"
" \K(\w+)(?= )"
```

or similar.

Comment: That is great! I keep wondering, though, if there isn't a more elegant solution at hand? In Java/C#'s Regex I wouldn't need this kind of work-arounds.

Comment: @devouredelysium: But then you are using the capturing group, or? As in `$1` or `\1` etc?

Comment: In C# I would refer to the first group, second, etc. I'm not  aware if the same is possible using grep?

Comment: @devouredelysium: One option is to use `pcregrep` as in `pcregrep -o1 " (\w+) "`. But then again that is not `grep`.

Comment: Perfect! 1234567

Comment: @devouredelysium it goes slightly more elegant since the capturing group does nothing. Something like `" \K.+?(?= )"` suffices

Answer (score 2):

A BRE doing what you're trying to in `sed` might look like:

```
sed 's/ *\(\([^ ]*\) *\)\{[num]\}.*/\2/'
```

...or as an ERE for those `sed`s which support it such as GNU and BSD versions:

```
sed -E 's/ *(([^ ]*) *){[num]}.*/\2/p'
```

...either expression will begin its match at the first character of the `[num]`th group *(where `[num]` is a positive integer)* of `[^ ]*`not-space characters in pattern-space and continue matching until line's end.

The important thing, though, is it subgroups some matches as it does so:

- `(([^ ]*) *){[num]}` - this group matches as many `[num]` occurrences of not-space groups and any/all subsequent space characters and can be back-reference as `\1`.

  - `{[num]}` - when a pattern is matched `\{[num]\}` times the only reference to it that remains is the last - and so even though this group matches as many occurrences of the pattern as specified, the only reference it returns is the last.
- `([^ ]*)` - the subgroup of the above group, though, matches only the subset of not-space characters matched in `\1`. This sub-group can be referenced in `\2`.
- `*` and `.*` - this matches any/all space characters leading pattern space and any/all characters following the occurrences matched in the subexpressions.
- `/\2/` - this replaces all of the above with only the group referenced in `\2`.

Because `[^ ]*` and `*` are boolean complements and that `[^ ]*`U`*` together can describe any possible string, the above regex works universally.

For your example:

```
for n in 1 2 3 4
do  echo "abc def ghi" | 
    sed -E "s/ *(([^ ]*) *){$n}.*/\2/"
done | sed -n l
```

...prints...

```
abc$
def$
ghi$
$
```

As is, it will always print a blank-line for a specified occurrence above that asked for, but - if that is not desirable - the line can be removed from output entirely like:

```
sed -En 's/ *(([^ ]*) *){[num]}.*/\2/;/./p'
```

Taking that a little further, the substitution can be applied globally to get only every `[num]`th occurrence. And since `*` is pretty limiting, I'll do it with `[[:space:]]*` instead - which will match any of `<space><tab><newline><vertical tab><return>`.

```
s=
{   printf "${s:=$(printf '\r\v\t%10s')}"
    seq -s"$s" 100
} | sed -En "s/[${s:=[:space:]}]*(([^$s]*)[$s]*){21}/\2\\
/g;      /[^$s]/s/\n*$//p"
```

Before applying `sed` to it the above `printf ...; seq ...` bit prints a single line like:

```
\r\v\t          1\r\v\t          2\r\v\t          3\r\v\t...
```

... and so on. But applying the above `sed` to it gets instead:

```
21
42
63
84
```

...and no blanks follow the numbers printed.