# grep -Eo -m 1 including extra characters after first match ; (treating a bracketed characters as a single pattern)

Tags: grep

I found this answer: [Group matching with grep includes extra characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179665/group-matching-with-grep-includes-extra-characters) but the anwser doesn't work for me.

I have a line in a json file that looks like this:

```
"object.0.1_foo": {
```

I want to match only the `:` in this case, other times I want to match the `{`.

```
grep -Eo -m 1 '[\:\{\}\[\]' <<<$object
```

returns `: {`

It was my understanding that characters inside brackets are the only thing searched for and if I ask for only the first match I should get just `:`

It seems like grep is treating `\:\{` as a single 'character'. What's really odd to me is if I use this regex:

```
grep -Eo -m 1 '[^\s][\:\{\}\[\]' <<<$object
```

to exclude the space trying to force grep to see : and { as two distinct characters it returns

```
":
```

which is really confusing to me because the `"` is not in my regex at all.

I can't figure out how to adjust my regex to only get the single match.

Comment: "I have a line in a json file that looks like this:" You shouldn't use `grep` on JSON content. JSON is structured you should leverage that with appropriate tools understanding JSON, like `jq`.

Comment: I'm just playing around with bash trying learn more about arrays and redirection. I realize bash is terrible tool for parsing JSON, but I thought it would be interesting to come up with something that didn't require an external tool. There are a couple scripts out there that do it and I'm seeing if I can come up with something different with my terrible bash skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-m 1` says to stop after 1 matching *line*; since there are two matching characters, `-o` will print them both (although it should be on two separate lines).

In addition, characters are literal inside `[..]` so `[^\s]` is matching any single character that is not `\` or `s`. In your case, that is the leading `"`.

If you really want to return only the `:`, then all you need is `grep -o ':'`

Comment: That is good to know about 1 matching line, I assumed it was just the match. Your answer explains everything. Thank you.